# Why we need to place Semicolon manually after this.. View

Tags: android

Why we need to place Semicolon manually?  after this

```
anyView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
@Override
public void onClick(){
   //Do something Here  
}

}) /// here will be an Error if we not place Semicolon ... Why Eclips not placing ; here?
}
```

I just want to make my concept clear....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the semicolon to complete the `anyView.setOnClickListener()` statement. Most of the time, Eclipse does not automatically complete your code statements for you - it cannot read your mind what was the code you intended to write.

What can be confusing is that the argument to `setOnClickListner()` is an anonymous inner class instance created inline and the syntax is a mixture of class definition and method calling.

Comment: Hi laalto... not most of the time... always eclips not put the semicolon for the code which I have posted above.. I belive there will be a some specific reason for this...